# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException on xp os

Tags: c#, window

i have develop Window application on visial studio 2010 and it is working fine on window 7 .But when I install setup on xp it is thrown error message as given below

> "Application: Measurement.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Stack: at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo,
>   System.Object, System.SignatureStruct ByRef,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectHolder)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
>
> "

Comment: We will actually need some code to help you. There could be numerous of problems that cause this exception to be thrown..

Comment: Does the XP computer have any service pack installed?